# Airtable - retrieve multiple records by id

Tags: airtable

I have seemingly a simple questions, I'm using airtable for the backend in my flutter app.

I know that I can retrieve a specific result from my table, by adding the record id at the end of the url. Like this:

```
/rec0PjvzbdWLP1sxM
```

But, how do I retrieve two or more results. Meaning, I have an array of records eg, [rec0Pj, recvzbd, recWLP. rec1sxM]. How can I make an API call to return just these records?

Do I use findByFormula, or some other way?

Thanks